# Combine multiple string.match functions into a single line

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a function where I need to check for special characters and break it if I find one.

Here is what I have tried.

```
local text = "h!ello\"wor%ld_t@xt.p^*sp&ki#$te"

if (string.match(text, "&") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end 

if (string.match(text, "\"") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end 

if (string.match(text, "#") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end 

if (string.match(text, "$") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end 

if (string.match(text, "@") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end

if (string.match(text, "%%") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end

if (string.match(text, "!") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end

if (string.match(text, "^") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end

if (string.match(text, "*") ~= nil) then
  print("Invalid Character \n")
end
```

I'm able to successfully do this, but I want everything in single line. Went through Lua Programming book but couldn't get.

Comment: `local p = string.find(text, '[&"#$@%!^*]'); if p then print("Invalid character found at "..p) end`

Comment: @EtanReisner: p is always nil in my case. It never prints.

Comment: That code works see https://eval.in/226658 and https://eval.in/226659

Comment: @EtanReisner: Thanks a ton. Post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match on one of a set of characters you need to use the `[set]` notation<sup>[1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)</sup>.

So the following should do what you want and provide a slightly better indication of the failure:

```
local p = string.find(text, '[&"#$@%%!^*]');

if p then
    print("Invalid character found at "..p)
end
```

You could even include the exact character that failed:

```
print("Invalid character '"..text:sub(p,p).."' at position "..p)
```

Comment: Wanted to point out here that your links in the comments show that the code works, almost. Take a look at the second test. "hello wor%ld_t@xt" printed invalid character at 15 (the @) instead of 10 (the %). I forget if the % needs to be doubled, though.

Comment: @Josh Good catch. Yes, `%` does need to be escaped as it is the escape character. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
if text:match '[&"#$@%%!^*]' then 
  print 'Invalid Character'
end
```